# WPF DataGrid binding not working for removing data

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have created a Datagrid using binding in WPF. Now I am trying to remove any element/clear the Datagrid by trying to manipulate the Datasource but the changes do not reflect in my Datagrid. 
Here is what I have done:
XAML-

```
    <DataGrid Name="XYZ" ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
      CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="20">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button Click="Button_Click"  Grid.Column="0">Edit</Button>
                                <Button Click="Delete_Button_Click" Grid.Column="1">Delete</Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

And here is the Property I have created the binding with-

```
            public List<ABC> GridItems
        {
        get
            {
            if ( null == m_gridItems )
                m_gridItems = new List<ABC>();
            return m_gridItems;
            }
        set
            {
            if ( value == m_gridItems )
                return;
            m_gridItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

P.S: The list is getting populated. But when I try to clear or remove any item from the GridItem, change is not getting reflected. Thank You.

Comment: Please paste the code of your delete method.

Comment: Look at the `ObservableCollection` (ie `INotifiyCollectionChanged`).